# What are the assumptions or conditions to consider when there is a diode parallel in a circuit ( both forward biased)?

Tags: diodes

[image: PARALLEL DIODE?]

Both diodes are in forward state.Si=0.7 and GaAs = 1.2.

Comment: My assumption from the schematic is both diodes are Si and share the current in R3

Comment: (assumed D1 is silicon and D2 is GaAS. )

Comment: You asked this question once before. We didn't do your homework then and we're not doing it now.

Comment: i am only asking for assumptions or conditions  to consider in analyzing the circuit..

Comment: What you should consider is how the current through a forward biased diode affect the voltage drop across that diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both diodes to be in parallel they must be connected having two common points.

You have different values for current because current differs with each component whereas voltage drop remains the same.

Comment: hmmm. which diode will turn ON first? or both diodes will turn ON during conduction?

Answer (score 0):

if you have identical diodes, at identical temperatures in identical circuits , which is your circuit, the forward voltage will be 18 millivolts lower than for just one diode --- for silicon, at room temperature.